# Producing hourly deltas out of full extracts

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The legacy pipeline is sending us the table which is about 300K rows in total.
And it sends the whole dataset to this hour. There are no datetime columns in there.

Is it possible implement the view containing a delta from the previous extract?
The one to have only those records added during last hour...

SQL EXCEPT comes to mind but I need to store the previous version of the table somehow.
Would appreciate any advice here.

Comment: Is the legacy pipeline writing to the same table and, if so, always appending, or dropping and reloading? If it's doing anything besides always appending, then consider setting up a new SCD2 table that you feed from the hourly 300k records (generally accomplished with a merge statement and some thoughtfulness). If it's always appending, then `EXCEPT` feels like a reasonable route.

Comment: Truncating and re-inserting

Comment: `SQL EXCEPT comes to mind but I need to store the previous version of the table somehow.` Snowflake is already doing that for you with Time Travel. This may also be a use case for a stream.

Comment: There's some good articles out there about how to implement scd2 on snowflake using stream tables and merge statements. Check out https://www.phdata.io/blog/implementing-slowly-changing-dimensions-in-snowflake/ for instance. If your orchestration is external and if you can add a step once the truncate/load occurs to run a procedure, you could skip the stream table part and just implement the merge that does the SCD2 logic to your target table. It's the route I would go if I were trying to build this to be relatively platform agnostic.

Comment: Dynamic tables also provide a simple approach to SCD. See https://medium.com/snowflake/slowly-changing-dimensions-with-dynamic-tables-d0d76582ff31 for an example.